# boto - more concise way to get key's value from bucket?

Tags: amazon-s3, boto

I'm trying to figure out a concise way to get data from s3 via boto

my current code looks like this.  s3 manager is simply a class that does all the s3 setup for my app.

```
    log.debug("generating downloader")
    downloader = s3_manager()

    log.debug("accessing bucket")
    bucket_archive = downloader.s3_buckets['@archive']

    log.debug("getting key")
    key = bucket_archive.get_key(archive_filename)

    log.debug("getting key into string")
    source = key.get_contents_as_string()
```

the problem is that , looking at my debug logs,  i'm making two requests to amazon s3:

```
    key = bucket_archive.get_key(archive_filename)
    source = key.get_contents_as_string()
```

looking at the docs [ http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/s3.html ] , it seems that the call to `get_key` checks to see if it exists , while the second call gets the actual data.  does anyone know of a method to do both at once ?  a more concise way of doing this with one request is preferable for our app.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `get_key()` method performs a HEAD request on the object to verify that it exists.  If you are certain that the bucket and key exist and would prefer not to have the overhead of a HEAD request, you can simply create a Key object directly.  Something like this would work:

```
import boto
s3 = boto.connect_s3()
bucket = s3.get_bucket('mybucket', validate=False)
key = bucket.new_key('myexistingkey')
contents = key.get_contents_as_string()
```

The `validate=False` on the call to `get_bucket` eliminates a GET request that also is intended to validate that the bucket exists.

Comment: Great. Thanks.  The relevant info I got from your response (and confirmed) was that instead of `get_key() + get_contents_as_string()` , I can call `new_key() + get_contents_as_string()` on an existing item.  i never would have thought about calling `new` on an existing item!

Comment: Well, the new method is really just a shortcut to create a Key object of a particular name with the reference to the bucket object already initialized.  You could also just create a key using Key(bucket, name).  I'm just lazy and didn't feel like having to import the Key class 8^)